# ¿How install ML-Agents?

Tags: 18.04, unity3d

I have ubuntu 18.04 and I want to install unity and ml-agents per hobby. I read the github documentation but I do not know what I do wrong because after doing the steps the ml-agents are not executed.
I have installed ml-agents, unity and tensorflow but I do not know if it is properly installed. 
Someone can help me? 
Thx.

Comment: Hello and welcome! A good starting point could be to explain all the steps you followed for the installation.

Comment: Hi and thx for reply. 
1. I'm downloaded Unity from this web https://beta.unity3d.com/download/dad990bf2728/public_download.html and execute the file for install. 
2. Later i download the ml agents with git clone https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents.git
3. cd ./ml-agents/ml-agents 
4. pip install -e.